# Detect non MFI register card reader to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, credit-card, serial-communication, external-accessory

I want to create a one application for communication of card reader with iPhone via dock connector. but problem is there my card reader accessory is not a MFI registered. so i cant get any kind of notification when i connect or disconnect device so please can any one tell me how can i connect or detect Non MFI registered accessory tot iPhone

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Mat, its already jailbroken but can you see me the way how can i detect it

Comment: What is the interface of the card reader? A Standard Serial RS232?

Comment: i am confuse hear but i think is dock-30 connector by the way i have no more knowledge for hardware side so little confused .

Comment: Hello Friends i got success with serial communication for detect accessory on iPhone now i am searching for communication between accessory and device if any one have any idea about how to communicate device and accessory please tell me... thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you say in your comment, it sounds a little strange(but not impossible) that the reader has the 30-pin-dock interface if it is not "Made for iPhone".
However if you are interested take a look at these refs(only for jailbreak device):
[iPhone Serial Port Tutorial](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial) and [iPhone Serial Communication](http://hcgilje.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/iphone-serial-communication/)

Let me know if you want a little more detail, once you figure out what kind of interface you have.

Comment: Hello mat ... i find out it's a Standard Serial RS232 . and if my device is jailbroken than EAAccessory framework can support or not ?